# How to get attribute's value from NTDS settings

Tags: powershell, active-directory, attributes

I am trying to read attribute's value from NTDS settings.
* You can view the settings with the GUI by open `Active Directory Sites and Services > Sites > Default-First-Site-Name > Servers > MyDCName > NTDS Settings`.
For the example, I am trying to read the `instanceType`'s value.
[image]

In the beginning I used [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Check-Active-Directory-9faf93b5) script.

I ran the following commands:

```
#Get the config partition DN
$Config = (Get-ADRootDSE).configurationNamingContext

#Use Get-ADObject to list server objects for current forest
$Servers = Get-ADObject -Filter {ObjectClass -eq "Server"} -SearchBase "CN=Sites,$Config" -SearchScope Subtree

#Test for NTDS Settings object
$Ntdsa = Get-ADObject -Filter {ObjectClass -eq "nTDSDSA"} -SearchBase "$(($Servers).DistinguishedName)" -SearchScope Subtree
```

But it doesn't give me the list of attributes from the NTDS.

I added another command:

```
Get-ADReplicationAttributeMetadata -Object $Servers -Server $Servers.Name
```

It gives me a list of small attributes, but lots are missings.

Any idea how I can do it ?

Comment: Add `-Properties *` to the last `Get-ADObject` query to get all the attribute values from the `nTDSDSA` object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-ADObject` only returns a limited set of attribute values by default. Use the `-Properties` parameter to specify additional attribute names:

```
# Specify * for all attribute values
$Ntdsa = Get-ADObject -Filter {ObjectClass -eq "nTDSDSA"} -Properties * -SearchBase "CN=Sites,$Config"
# or
# Specify a list of attribute names
$Ntdsa = Get-ADObject -Filter {ObjectClass -eq "nTDSDSA"} -Properties 'instanceType','msDS-Behavior-Version' -SearchBase "CN=Sites,$Config"

# This should now return a value
$Ntdsa.instanceType
```

Comment: Thanks, but why it doesn't show **all** the attributes ? For example, the attribute `msDS-NcType` doesn't appear when I use this query but on the GUI it appears.

Comment: Ah because it was `<not set>`, ok so everything is ok. Thanks !

Comment: @E235 Yes, it's likely because the attribute has never been set on the object. You can retrieve all possible contained attributes from the schema (that's what the GUI does), but you probably don't need to